# Can a statement claim itself to be unprovable?

Tags: logic

If so then there is at least one x 
such that x = "x is unprovable":

1) x = "x is unprovable"

It must now be true that:

2) x is provable IFF "x is unprovable" is provable

Since only true sentences are provable simplification gets a contradiction:

3) x is provable IFF x is unprovable

And we must conclude that there is no statement claiming itself to be unprovable. (QED)

---

Addendum

---

As to formal systems: They may perhaps produce statements saying that they are unprovable in the formal system ... which is true if the system is consistent.

That is a restricted concept of unprovability.

It has been said that the term "unprovable" is vague.

That it is relative and needs a qualification such as "Unprovable by ruler and compass" ...
 But I think there is a basic meaning that can be defined:

(definition) x is unprovable IFF there can be no proof of x.

Comment: Gödel's theorem exactly is such a statement. Do you try to prove it's wrong?

Comment: Gödels formula is not an unprovable formula: 
It does NOT claim itself to be unprovable!
It claims that it is not provable in Peano Arithmetics ... 
Which we can see is true or  Peano Arithmetics is inconsistent.

Comment: Claiming something != demonstration nor proof of claim.

Comment: No, Gödel's Theorem can't be formulated in too weak arithmetics, where all true statements are provable. And any arithmetics where Gödel's Theorem can be formulated, has unprovable statements.

Comment: *provable* is relative to a context (a theory). Speaking of "absolute" provability is vague.

Comment: Do I remember it wrong? Did not Gödel use the Peano system in order to construct his proof? My point is that Gödel used a restricted version of unprovability.  By creating a sentence claiming it couldnt be proven by the system that created the sentence. In my proof above I use an unrestricted form of provability. Just like we may use an unrestricted form of truth.  Are you going to claim truth is relative next? The truth is that x is unprovable IFF there is no proof of x!

Comment: The above is not a proof; an informal proof has many many unwritten assumptions: where are yours ?

Comment: Maybe "natural logic" (the logic usually used with natural language arguments) is *inconsistent*: in such case, every statement is provable and thus there are **no** *unprovable* statements.

Comment: Paradoxes are just the human mind reaching the limits of what it was designed to comprehend, they are not proof of the invalidity of a claim.

Comment: First) Im not aware of any unwritten assumptions. If you find any that will effect the proof then point them out please!
Second) The steps should be obvious to most logic students.
The step from the assumption in line1 to line 2 is motivated by Leibniz law, and the next step from line 2 to line 3 by the Definition of truth.  Third) And I have not yet made any claims as to what paradoxes are.

Comment: Simply : on what "axiom" ir principle are you asserting that : "x is provable IFF "x is unprovable" is provable" ? Compare with : "x is **black** IFF "x is not **black**" is **black**".

Comment: I use the rule: The indiscernibility of identicals , given By Leibniz. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles 
It says: For any x and y, if x is identical to y, then x and y have all the same properties. So having a=b we may derive Za IFF Zb .
So having that x = "x is unprovable , then  Leibniz Law enables me to deduce that x is provable IFF  "x is unprovable" is provable.

Comment: What do you mean by "a statement *claim* that it is unprovable."  I think the issue may be that, using slightly different wordings, a statement can assert that it is, itself, unprovable, as long as it can't prove it.  I find that there's nothing contradictory about (2), but (3) is a contradiction, so I see the issue must be there.  I'm not sure what law you are applying there, but I think it may be something that presumes a proof of a statement, rather than merely an assertion.

Comment: You can't prove anything without axioms (so Gödel's theorem is not provable without any arithmetics). Same is yours. You need some rules to make conclusions. In either way you may say PA is inconsistent, therefore Gödel's theorem is wrong. Thus, we are getting a self-referential paradox. What you do here is similar.

Comment: "(definition) x is unprovable IFF there can be no proof of x." lol. Take an introduction to symbolic logic class and I promise you everything you're not understanding here will make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake here is that 2) and 3) are not equivalent. Not all true statements are provable, so you can't simplify "x is provable" to "x is true", since it is a stronger statement to say `y IFF x provable` than to say `y IFF x`.

Answer (score 0):

Godel's incompleteness theorem essentially states that any formal system complicated enough to create a statement like "This statement is not provable" is either inconsistent (some statements are both true and false) or incomplete (some true statements are unprovable within the system).

It seems that you are trying to get around this problem by redefining what is allowed to be a statement.  One could certainly alter a logical system by adding the rule that any valid statement must be provably true or provably false.  Such a system would no longer be incomplete, though it might become either inconsistent or trivial (no statements exist).

Comment: "this statement is unprovable" cant say that it itself is unprovable   because then it must be the case that  

1) this statement is identical with "this statement is not provable".     
But if so then    
2) this statement is provable IFF "this statement is not provable" is provable.  
Provable sentences are true  so we get.
4)  this statement is provable IFF this statement is not provable 

The result is that "this statement is unprovable" cant be used to say that it itself is unprovable. 

Your formal system can only produce sentences saying that the formal system cant prove them.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) x is provable IFF "x is unprovable" is provable

Following the defintion in Premise 1, Premise 2 is saying the following: the hypothesis that Statement X is unprovable is itself provable if and only if it is possible to prove that such hypotheses are provable. The statement is actually closer to a tautology.

Premise 2 does not assist the conclusion that Statement X is provable if and only if Statement X is unprovable.

Answer (score 0):

"P is unprovable" is a poor attempt at the Liar Paradox. "P is unprovable" if it is logically unprovable (for instance, P is a metaphysical proposition) or by enumeration, it is justifiable to assert "P is unprovable" (such is the case with "I exist").

"This statement is false" is the introductory statement to how language and propositions work, and most importantly, that the LNC is a strategy rather than a law (as Dialetheism attests to).

Given the following, "This statement is false" doesn't express a proposition:

P = [content][is or is not the case]

b = [it is true that] P

d = [it is not true that] P

a = b or d [as declarative speech act]

Where P is "proposition", b is "belief", d is "doubt", and a is "assertion".

The dialectic analysis of P (according to Peirce, Russell, and others) is:

P = [This sentence][is false]

And so, "This sentence" doesn't purport to be about any state of affairs and then cannot be true or false.

Answer (score 0):

"Proof" is a vague word.  I'd say that a proof is an ordered set of transformations of statements starting with premises and ending with the conclusion.  It is therefore necessary to have specific premises and legal transformations, which pretty much means that proofs have to be in formal systems.

It is possible to have other definitions of proof, I suppose:  "I tell you once, I tell you twice/What I tell you three times is true" could be taken as a method of proving things (although not a really useful one).  In that case, anything that can be pronounced can be proven, including 'This statement is unprovable." when you repeat it three times.

So, what do you mean by "proof"?  It has a clear meaning in a formal system, and in a formal system it is possible to come up with "Statement X:  X is unprovable."  If you consider proof outside a formal system, you still need to put some limits on it.